# Where are the files for Adobe (CS5.5) InDesign's *export as XHTML*?

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript

From Adobe's [GETTING STARTED WITH ADOBE
INDESIGN CS5.5
PLUG-IN DEVELOPMENT](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/indesign/cs55-docs/InDesignProducts/getting-started.pdf) (page 112):

> In InDesign CS5, the Export as XHTML/Dreamweaver feature is
>   implemented completely using  ExtendScript. Export as
>   XHTML/Dreamweaver is not distributed as a traditional InDesign
>   plug-in; instead, it  is installed as a folder containing several
>   ExtendScript binaries, within the InDesign scripts folder located in 
>   /Scripts/export as XHTML. The source code for
>   Export as XHTML is included in 
>   /source/public/components/xhtmlexport.

However, at the beginning of that chapter (named *Feature Development with Scripting*), there is a notice saying:

> **Chapter Update Status**
>
> CS5.5    Unchanged    Content not guaranteed to
>   be current.

Indeed, I can find neither the binaries nor the source for the *export as XHTML* script as neither the `<InDesignInstallFolder>/Scripts/export as XHTML` folder nor the `<SDK>/source/public/components/xhtmlexport` folder exist in the CS5.5 versions of InDesign and the SDK.

(I got the SDK from [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/indesign/sdk/eula_cs55.html).)

Does anyone know where I can find the source code for the *export as XHTML* script?

Answer (score 1):

The source code for the export as xhtml script may have been compiled into native code in InDesign CS5.5; previously it was written in javascript.

In InDesign CS5, the source files are located within the InDesign bundle itself (if you are running on Mac), although they are jsxbin files, so they are not human readable (and can't really be modified for that reason unfortunately). This is the directory where I found them on my system:

```
/Applications/Adobe InDesign CS5/Scripts/XHTML For Digital Editions
```

In InDesign CS5.5, those source files are missing which is why I'm guessing they were refactored.

Comment: Do you know if they were ever provided as .jsx? As part of an SDK perhaps?

Comment: Oh wait! I _just_ found it in the SDK, I'm sorry about that. Here is the path where I found it in the SDK folder `source/public/components/xhtmlexport`. It seems to include the actual source files, so they were not compiled like I originally thought. (This is the CS5 SDK by the way, not the CS5.5 SDK.) If you have to go backwards a version to CS5, the SDK can be downloaded here: [http://www.adobe.com/devnet/indesign/sdk.html](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/indesign/sdk.html)